# Heroku sign-on process asking for lost authenticator code

Tags: heroku

How do I associate a QR Code from my Heroku accounts with my android Authentication App being that I am locked out of my account (Catch 22).

It's been a while since I last logged into Heroku and now trying to sign-on,the process is asking for Verification Code from my Authentication App. However, I no longer have the association between the Heroku QR Code and my Authentication App. Everything I do to try in resolve (email support, make a admin request, get to admin settings/QR Code, etc.) requires that I log in first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [we literally cannot help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Contact Heroku support. (Note that this is exactly what MFA is supposed to do. If you can't provide a token, you can't log in. In the future I strongly suggest that you configure an alternate MFA source and / or save your recovery codes.)

Comment: "Everything I do to try in resolve (email support, make a admin request, get to admin settings/QR Code, etc.) requires that I log in first"—create a throwaway account if you have to. Your only option is to get in touch with Heroku support.